# How to set attribute to its default value

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for a way to update a record attribute with its default value (the one that's defined in the DEFAULT statement), without specifying the value explicitly in the UPDATE statement.
Pls help.

Comment: `update mytab set col = default where <whatever>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update to `DEFAULT` if there is a default specified in the schema definition for that column.

**For example:**

```
update mytable set mycol=default where id=1;
```